# NetSuite, Mass Update Memorized Transactions

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I have a need to be able to update a large number of memorized transactions, namely sales orders. So, the transactions are generated, but there may or may not be certain fields that need to be updated each time they are generated. A coworker of mine tried a mass update, and I tried doing some scripted updates, and we both were greeted with the same error: **MEMORIZED_TRANS_ERROR - Attempting to access memorized transaction as a non-memorized transaction**. Is there a way to accomplish such a mass edit/update and avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

Would help if you showed some code but a guess is you are using the wrong record type. It should be `memdoc`. The help topic **Memorized Transaction Definition** has example code.

> **Sample Code**
>
> Memorized transaction definitions can only be created in the NetSuite user interface. The example script below first loads an existing memorized transaction definition with ID 2. Then, it sets the Action field to “Reminder”, and sets the Next Transaction Date in the Custom Dates subtab to 12/12/2020. It saves this date, and then saves the memorized transaction definition.
>
> ```
> var r = nlapiLoadRecord('memdoc', 2)
> r.setFieldValue('action', 'REMINDER')
> r.selectNewLineItem('customdates')
> r.setCurrentLineItemValue('customdates', 'nextdate', '12/12/2020')
> r.commitLineItem('customdates')
> var id = nlapiSubmitRecord(r);
> ```

Comment: Well, that's the problem. The need isn't to update the 'memdoc' record, but the sales order itself. because at this point, the memorized transaction is set to automatically create a new order, and the order has been created, but a handful of fields need to be updated each time with new information. Setting the next date on the 'memdoc' record won't achieve the intended goal.

Comment: @MichaelMcCauley Reminder that nobody can see what you are actually trying to do. Having to figure out what you are trying to do, how you are trying to do it in a way that fails and then come up with a solution is just too much.